# buildbot force build ignoring repository

Tags: buildbot

When I click on the 'builders' link of builbot URL and force a build, the git repository I specify on the form is getting ignored; the builder is using the repository it was originally built/configured with. Is this a known problem ? Is there some way to force the builder to use the new repo ? I'm running 0.8.4 on Ubuntu 10.04. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you run reconfig on the server? I haven't had an issue moving things around in my current setup --using 0.8.5.

Answer (score 1):

This is a deliberate choice, as there various potential ways of creating a source stamp, that are insecure. Thus, someone could potentially execute arbitrary code on the slave, if buildbot used whatever repository URL passed into it.

That said, it is easy to get the behavior you want. The simplest is to specify
`repourl=Property('repository', '<default-repository>')`
which will use the 'repository' property of the build (which gets initialized from the source stamp) or the default repository, if none is specified. (`Property` is imported from `buildbot.process.properties`)